# Autoresize gridview columns header according to their data

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridview, datacolumn

How I can auto resize each data column header on my gridview according to their data and it should be fit to the screen without scrollbars to view the remaining data in the grid? Heres my sample code..

Xaml:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="First Name" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Last Name" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Middle Name" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding MiddleName}"  />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Registration Day" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding RegistrationDay, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDynamicHyperlinkColumn Header="Email" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Email}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Password" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Access}" />
```

Hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: do you mean equally distribute the space across the width? or you want the columns to resize according to data in the column?

Comment: to resize according to the data in the column. And also, the data in the row, if it exceed to text that i input, instead of wrapping the text, i want to display "...." Something like that.

Comment: and also a follow up question about the grid that whenever I double click the whole row, it will show the a dialog box. Instead of clicking my edit button.. Is that possible?

Comment: do columns have a maximum size? it is required for `...`. Secondly double click behavior is indeed possible.

Comment: @pushpraj Yes they have a size. On my xaml, i just put '*' in each header. If the text for every column exceed, it will just this '...'. Can you help me how to figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example showing answers to most of the points in the question

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock"
               x:Key="trimStyle">
            <Setter Property="TextTrimming"
                    Value="CharacterEllipsis" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Resize to header width"
                            Width="SizeToHeader"
                            Binding="{Binding}"
                            ElementStyle="{StaticResource trimStyle}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Resize to cell content"
                            Width="SizeToCells"
                            Binding="{Binding}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Resize to header &amp; cell content"
                            Width="Auto"
                            Binding="{Binding}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Distribute the remaining space"
                            Width="Auto"
                            Binding="{Binding}"
                            ElementStyle="{StaticResource trimStyle}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <sys:String>a string which is long</sys:String>
    <sys:String>a string which is long, a really long string</sys:String>
    <sys:String>another string which is long</sys:String>
    <sys:String>another string which is long, a really long string</sys:String>
</DataGrid>
```

result

[image: result]

as you can see that we have few modes of column sizing which determines the width of column. For ellipsis `...` on long text I have defined a style for TextBlock with TextTrimming options enabled and used the same as ElementStyle for the desired columns

refer to [Sizing Options in the DataGrid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903935(v=vs.95).aspx) for details on datagrid sizing options

the example is based on `DataGrid` but seems like you are using teleric controls, but I am sure it would apply to the teleric controls in similar manner. I do not have teleric controls so I may not flash an example for the same.

Comment: It does not support the telerik. However, I got the idea on your example given. Another thing, would it be possible that since i used the textrimming, when i hover my mouse to the cell in my gridview, is it possible to view it?

Comment: you may use tool tip here, so perhaps adding `<Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding}" />` or `<Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />` in the textblock's style should do the trick.

Comment: It doesnt work..  I think it not hover. Maybe when you click the cell, that the time that the tooltip will show up..